# Api route pattern on the SlimPhp microframework?

Tags: php, slim

Is there some pattern of routes and how to write the structure using SlimPhp?

Like, I made a api folder with a index.php to store ALL my routes:

```
$app->get('/api/shirt/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response) { 
    //CODE
});
$app->get('/api/some-other-endpoint/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response)
    //CODE
});
```

But after some time, I realized that my index file will get pretty big.

So, how can I manage my endpoint routes? Using classes, controllers, actions?

Where can I find documentation about these particular concepts?

Comment: To build an API faster you might want to switch to Laravel and use [resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers). Same route syntax!

Comment: i will read about laravel. But i'm trying to find some solution using slim php. Like some controller package, because i'd like to stay using slim instead of changing framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using controller's (named Action's in this example) and still have all routing in one file.

Additionally I use grouping whereever I can because it give a better structure (in my opinion).
I try to make the Action-classes as small as possible that I do not need to look at the routes-file for getting the class which I want to change.

Here an example:

*Routes-File*:

```
$app->get('/user/{name}', [ShowUserAction::class, 'showUser'])->setName('user');
$app->get('/login', [LoginUserAction::class, 'showLogin'])->setName('login');

$app->group('/api', function () {
    $this->get('/images', [ImagesApi::class, 'getImages'])->setName('api.images');
    $this->get('/tags', [ImagesApi::class, 'getTags'])->setName('api.tags');
    $this->get('/notifications', [UserNotificationsApiAction::class, 'getNotifications'])->setName('api.notifications');
    $this->get('/bubbleCount', [BubbleCountApiAction::class, 'getBubbleCount'])->setName('api.bubbleCount');
});

$app->group('/review', function() use ($currentUser) {
   $this->get('', [ReviewAction::class, 'showReviewOverview'])->setName('review.overview')->setName('review')
   $this->get('/{type}', [ReviewAction::class, 'showReviewWithType'])->setName('review.type')
   $this->get('/{type}/{id}', [ReviewAction::class, 'showReview'])->setName('review.type.id')
});
```

*Action-class*:

```
class LoginUserAction
{
    public function __construct() { }  // with parameters

    public function showLogin(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        if ($this->currentUser->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('index'));
        }

        return $this->view->render($response, 'user/login.twig');
    }

    public function doLogin(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        // check user name password and then login
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to what i was thinking, and think i can apply something like this to my project. Because I like using classes.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have my own router before I involve Slim's router to determine which route to use based on the path after the domain:

public/index.php

```
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App;
require 'app/routes/index.php';
$app->run();
```

app/routes/index.php

```
$_url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$_routes = explode('/',$_url['path']);
$_baseRoute = $_routes[1];

switch ($_baseRoute) {
    case 'api':
        $_routeFile = 'app/api/' . $_routes[2] . '.php';
        break;

    default:
        $_routeFile = 'app/routes/' . $_baseRoute . '.php';
        break;
}

if (file_exists($_routeFile)) {
    require $_routeFile;
}
else {
    die('Invalid API request');
}
```