# how to use a dependency container in a php file that isn't a class in Slim 3

Tags: php, dependency-injection, slim, pimple

I have this dependency container for my database.

```
$container['db'] = function ($container) {
    $db = $container['settings']['db'];
    $conn = db2_connect($db['database'], $db['username'], $db['password']);
    return $conn;
};
```

I can use this in my controller like this `$conn = $this->db;` to query my database and return an array.

I am trying to do an ajax call to use datatables in a view. When I create a page for my ajax call it's just a php file. Not a class. How do I use the db container in this php file?

here is the php file.

```
if ($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT trannum, 
                   trantype, 
                   tranbatch, 
                   trandate, 
                   username, 
                   trvnum, 
                   tranaccount, 
                   tranamt, 
                   transtatus, 
                   trannumdocs 
            FROM   BD.BDPTV 
                   INNER JOIN BD.BDUSERS 
                           ON BD.BDUSERS.usernumber = BD.BDPTV.tranuser 
            WHERE  transtatus NOT IN ( 3, 7, 5 )";

    $stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);

    if ($stmt) {
        $result = db2_execute($stmt);
        if ($result) {
            while ($row = db2_fetch_array($stmt)) {
                $admin[] = array(
                    'trnum' => $row[0],
                    'trtyp' => $row[1],
                    'trbatch' => $row[2],
                    'trdate' => $row[3],
                    'usrnam' => $row[4],
                    'trvnum' => $row[5],
                    'tracct' => $row[6],
                    'tramt' => $row[7],
                    'trvsts' => $row[8],
                    'numdoc' => $row[9]
                );
            }
        } else {
            error_log(db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt));
        }
    } else {
        error_log(db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt));
    }
} else {
    error_log(db2_conn_errormsg());
}

multiDim($admin);
$admin['data'] = $admin;
echo json_encode($admin);
```

Comment: `function () use ($container) {` would better suit.

Comment: Um, when communicating between php and javascript, your best bet is to use JSON strings.

 function respond($result){
    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    exit(json_encode($result));
  }

Comment: @LawrenceCherone do I wrap my whole php file in ```function () use ($container) {```?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the `db`-object in 2 ways first the 'array' style (like you've defined it)

```
$conn = $container['db'];
```

or via the `get`-method

```
$conn = $container->get('db');
```

Nevertheless you should add a route in Slim to do that, not add an extra PHP file for that. This is not the usecase for Slim.

Comment: Can you explain this "Nevertheless you should add an route in Slim to do that"

Comment: @moe You can add a route like defined in [here](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html), at the end you can then use `$response->withJson($admin);` Then it should work the same as the php file.

Comment: So I would have a response in my controller and one in my route?

Comment: @moe A controller is the class version of a route, you only need one, [you can have a look at this, for how I structur my controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45197291/4244993)

Comment: Right, that's exactly how I have my router/controller setup now. Let me take a step back. I've only been using Slim for a couple weeks. I am trying to use datatables in my view so I need to make an ajax call. What is the best way/structure to do this?

Comment: @moe you should add a new question for that. This question was answered by this answer.

Comment: If i'm trying to use this dependency in a class do I need a ```use``` statement?

Comment: @moe, nope, you need to include parts of the slim start up where you define the container and the $container['db'] otherwise that cannot be found.

Comment: I don't understand this "parts of the slim start up"

Comment: @moe like include the vendor folder and initialising the Container ([like in here](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/di.html))